# Stuck With UIViewAutoresizingMask

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios6, ipad-2

Hi I am New in iOS Development I added `UITableViewCell` With Custom Cell Design in which I

added two labels in one Cell for which I added

> ```
> UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(/* where you want it*/)];
> label.text = @"text"; //etc...
> label.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
> [self.contentView addSubView:label];
> [label release];
> ```

where my First Label is masking but second Label is Sticking while repositioning table

I am Using iOS6

Comment: post the full code of creating `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Which iOS version you going to used?